# Building a controller that changes a variable in a POST request via form (Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I had question regarding how to configure a controller to change a variable via a form. I'm currently using Thymeleaf for templating, and I followed the Spring documentation to set up my controller.

Right now, my controller successfully creates a new instance of class "Bill" whenever a request is made...

```
@Controller
public class BudgetController {

@Autowired
private BillBook book;

@GetMapping("/")
public String billForm(ModelMap modelMap, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("bill", new Bill());
    modelMap.put("billName", name);
    return "home";
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String billSubmit(Model model, @ModelAttribute Bill bill) {
      book.addToBillBook(bill);
      return "redirect:/";
}

}
```

...and passes that into a list in class "BillBook".

```
@Component
public class BillBook {
private List<Bill> billList;
private int paycheckTotal;
private int difference;
private int billTotal;


public BillBook() {
    billList = new ArrayList<>();
    paycheckTotal = 0;
    difference = 0;
    billTotal = 0;
}

public void addToBillBook(Bill bill) {
    billList.add(bill);
}

public void setPaycheckTotal(int amount) {
    paycheckTotal = amount;
}

public int getPaycheckTotal () {
    return paycheckTotal;
}
```

This is done every time a user inputs a bill name into a form that I've structured in Thymeleaf.

```
<h1>Form</h1>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${bill}" method="post">
    <p>Bill name <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
    <p>Bill amount <input type="text" th:field="*{amount}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" 
    value="Reset"/></p>
</form>
```

I'm aware that I still need to make some changes, so that the amount is also included, but right now this works fairly well.

However, what I want to do now is to allow the user to input a paycheck amount into the form, which should be stored in the "paycheckTotal" variable in the BillBook class. I want this to be a constant -- i.e., the user can only submit one paycheck and every time they enter a new paycheck, it overwrites the prior one.

From my research, I believe this should be done via the @RequestParam annotation. Something like this, perhaps?

```
public String billSubmit(Model model, @ModelAttribute Bill bill, 
@RequestParam ("paycheckTotal") int paycheckTotal) {
```

But I'm not sure how to structure this in the Thymeleaf template so that it is stored in the paycheckTotal variable.

If anyone could show me how that should be constructed, it would be really, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${bill}" method="post">
    <p>Bill name <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
    <p>Bill amount <input type="text" th:field="*{amount}" /></p>
    <p>Paycheck total <input type="text" th:value="${paycheckTotal}" th:name="paycheckTotal"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" 
    value="Reset"/></p>
</form>
```

If you need default value, you can also add:

```
model.addAttribute("paycheckTotal", paycheckTotal);
```